# Server side time validation for timepicker. End time must be greater that start time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, datetime, kendo-ui

I have a MVC application where my `StartTime` and `EndTime` are of type `timespan`. I have used Kendo UI for time picker.

**Is it possible to validate the end time in such way that end time must be greater than start time on the server side?** I want the error to be shown without user having to submit the form.

This is current code in view for timepicker

```
    <div class="label">Select Start Time</div>
    <br/>
    <div>@Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(model=>model.StartTime)</div>
    <br/>
    <div class="label">Select End Time</div>
    <div>@Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(model=>model.EndTime)</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listeners for every time when `StartTime` or `EndTime` change (look for a specific event for the Kendo TimePicker). So add any validation logic in these listeners such as sending the dates to the server through an ajax request and validate them on the server side.

Also the best practice is to validate data for ajax requests on the client side and only then send it on the server side.